# Mocha before hook not executing correctly

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

I'm setting up a test suite with Mocha, on an ExpressJS app. In the test, I want to drop all models in a collection before the suite runs, and I"m doing the following:

```
var Users = require("../models/Users").model;

before(function(done){
    Users.remove({}, function(){
    console.log("removed");
    done();
});

//rest of the test suite here
```

The trouble is, this before hook is timing out. What am I missing here? BTW, if I change this to be an after hook, the result is the same - it never drops the models, and times out.

Comment: What ORM are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Mocha timeouts all tests that take more than 2 sec by default.
Try this:

```
var Users = require("../models/Users").model;

this.timeout(5000); //sets timeout to 5 sec

before(function(done){
   Users.remove({}, function(){
   console.log("removed");
   done();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable timeout as specified [in the manual](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#test-specific-timeouts).